# How to refresh the cached title of a page Liked on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-like

I have a couple of embedded YouTube videos which I have added Like buttons for.  The titles were wrong the first time I tested the Like functionality.

Although the video titles have now been changed, the old titles are still showing up in a user's news feed when they click Like.

Is there a way to get Facebook to get the new titles of the page, or are the titles now cached forever?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Facebook URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to refresh the data. This tool is ment for debugging open graph tags on webpages. It has nice side effect of updating Facebook cache of the debugged URL. Originally this tool was named [Facebook URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/390/).

Comment: Thanks Mika, this worked apart from in the comment box popover that appears when someone clicks the Like button.  For some reason that is still using the old title.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I do not know any other way. Using debugger usually fixes things for me. But I am not surprised if it does not always work. Facebook works in mysterious ways :)